# Split files and process in chunks

Tags: r, bash, for-loop, chunks

I believe this is pretty simple, but so far I've had no luck.

I have a directory containing many large files which I split and move to /temp. I then proceed to process the files using script.R.

```
# create temp dir
mkdir -p "$1/temp"

# split and move files to /temp
for file in "$1"/*; do

  split --verbose -b 10M --numeric-suffixes "$file" "$file"
  mv -t "$1/temp" "$1/"*[0-99]

done

# process files in /temp
script.R "$1/temp"
```

The splitting of files result in nearly 8000 files. And for some reason the whole process crashes past a couple of thousand files. This is a problem which I have no idea how to construct a question for. :)

When I test this on smaller number of files it runs smoothly which is why I would like to perform the whole thing in chunks.

So how do I split, let's say, 10 files at a time, process them and then move on to the next 10 files.

I believe this can be achieved using xargs, nested for loops and other approaches... But welp, I'm a GNU noob.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *`whole process crashes`* ... and no error messages?  I'm guessing the issue is related to `mv -t "$1/temp" "$1/"*[0-99]` ... what is this supposed to do?  consider adding `set -x` (to enable debug mode) before the `for` loop, run the script, and review the debug output

Comment: Try adding ```sleep 2``` after the last ```mv``` command.

Comment: Yes, I get an error msg of course, but I will have to get back on that since it takes around 6 hours before the crash occurs. My bad, I should have saved it...

I've already tried the `sleep` trick. At first I thought the the mv process was not finished when script.R was fired, but it made no difference. 

Thanks for your comments! :)

Comment: The error message:
`Error in unserialize(node$con) : 
  MultisessionFuture (<none>) failed to receive results from cluster RichSOCKnode #1 (PID 5251 on ‘localhost’). The reason reported was ‘error reading from connection’. Post-mortem diagnostic: The total size of the 9 globals exported is 321.43 KiB. The three largest globals are ‘...furrr_chunk_args’ (239.44 KiB of class ‘list’), ‘...furrr_chunk_seeds’ (66.48 KiB of class ‘list’) and ‘...furrr_map_fn’ (7.23 KiB of class ‘function’)
Calls: future_walk2 ... resolved -> resolved.ClusterFuture -> receiveMessageFromWorker
Execution halted`

Comment: Wait. Script.R is a parallelized operation that I've set to use 10 R sessions. After the error it seems to continue on 5. I dont know how to make sense of the error message but it might finish the job despite it. WEIRD!

Comment: Nevermind. The script processed ~1200 more files before finally coming to an end. 

If some of you guys have a solution to do this in chunks, I think that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this script:

```
cd "$1" || exit

# create temp dir
rm -rf temp && mkdir temp || exit

# split files to temp
for file in *; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        split --verbose -b 10M --numeric-suffixes "$file" temp/"$file"
    fi
done

# process files in temp
script.R temp
```

Comment: This works just like my previous solution on a smaller test sample. I will try and run this on the full batch, but I'm not sure this will make any difference. 
Do you know how to perform this in chunks? 
For what it's worth, I will be able to show the error message, if/when the thing crashes again. :)